# Is this an allowed interaction?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, conservation-laws, standard-model, weak-interaction

I am looking to understand whether this reaction is allowed:

$$e^+ + e^- \rightarrow K^0 + \pi^0.$$

1. Baryon number is conserved
2. Charge is conserved
3. Total intrinsic spin of underlying particles is integral on both sides - angular momentum could be conserved with orbital angular momentum
4. Lepton number is conserved
5. Strangeness is not conserved

This implies if the reaction were to occur it would have to be through the weak force. Question is - how do I know if it is possible via the weak force? Do I need to just try Feynman diagrams to see if I can get one to work?

Comment: Do you know about “no strangeness-changing neutral currents?”

Comment: I do. However it appears to me the interaction would not necessarily need to remain neutral through all vertices? For example, if the $e^+ + e^-$ couple to a $Z$ boson and the Z boson couple to some combination of quarks or $W$ bosons which aren't neutral, there would not need to be a flavour changing neutral current?

Comment: So you understand it can't go through at the tree level. You may now find a box diagram involving two Ws, but you must know how very-very-very small that is...  Estimate it. No good faith instructor would expect a box diagram answer.

Comment: And compare to $K_S\to π^0 e^+ e^−$, which has been observed! Batley, J.R., Kalmus, G.E., Lazzeroni, C., Munday, D.J., Patel, M., Slater, M.W., Wotton, S.A., Arcidiacono, R., Bocquet, G., Ceccucci, A. and Cundy, D., (2003) *Observation of the rare decay* $K_S\to π^0 e^+ e^−$ Phys Lett **B576** (1-2) pp43-54.